# How to return values recursively

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion

I've been trying to get my head around recursion, but i can't seem to figure out how to quit a function/return a value recursively.

Given a binary tree of integer values and a target value, i'm trying to find and return the node with the closest value to the target.

I'm able to traverse the binary tree, and eventually find a node that matches a target, however when i return the value, it does not stop the function calls and return the matching value, but continues on. Eventually, i seem to return the difference between the initial node, and the target instead of the correct values.

Could anyone shed some light on how i can go about doing it?

Thanks!

This was an assignment, and this is the answer that i submitted.

```
class TreeNode:
"""
Reference based Binary Tree Node.
"""
def __init__(self, key, data, leftPtr = None, rightPtr = None):
    """
    [key] and [data] are expected.
    """
    self.key = key
    self.data = data
    self.leftT = leftPtr
    self.rightT = rightPtr

def toString(self):
    return "[K:%d|D%s | left at %d |right at %d]"%(self.key, self.data, self.leftT, self.rightT)

class BTSimple:
    """
    Simplified BT implemented with reference
    """
    def __init__(self, vList):
        """
        Construct a BT base on the [vList]
        vList has the format [root, [Left Tree], [Right Tree]], 
            where left and right tree has the same format
        """
        self._root = self._buildBT(vList)
        self._size = len(vList)

def _buildBT(self, vList):

    if vList == []:
        return None

    t = TreeNode(vList[0], str(vList[0]))

    if len(vList) > 1:
        t.leftT = self._buildBT(vList[1])
        t.rightT = self._buildBT(vList[2])

    return t

def _spaces(level):
    """
    Internal helper method to generate 4 spaces per level.
    """
    return ' '*(level*4)

def _pPrintRecursive(self, T, level):
    """
    Internal helper method to do "pretty" printing of AVL Tree.
    """
    if T == None:
        return

    self._pPrintRecursive(T.rightT, level+1)

    print(BTSimple._spaces(level), end='')
    print(T.key, end='')
    if T.leftT != None or T.rightT != None:
        print("---")
    else:
        print()
    self._pPrintRecursive(T.leftT, level+1)

def prettyPrint(self):
    """
    Print the Binary Tree in more visual way. 
    """
    self._pPrintRecursive(self._root, 0)


def _closestR(self,tree,target,closest = 9999):

    if tree is None:
        print("Tree is none, returning....")
        return
    print("Initialising _closestR..")
    print ("Current treenode is " + str(tree.data) + ", with the target being " + str(target))
    #Search for the exact match first
    #If no exact match, find closest
    #Use pre-order traversal
    distance = abs(target - tree.key)
    if distance < closest:
        closest = distance

    if distance == 0:
        return tree.key
    print("before traversing left, distance is " + str(distance) + " and closest is " + str(closest))
    valueL = self._closestR(tree.leftT,target,closest)
    if valueL is not None:
        print(valueL)
        return valueL
    else:
        print("None returned. Tree is : " + str(tree.key))
    valueR = self._closestR(tree.rightT,target,closest)
    if valueR is not None:
        print(valueR)
        return valueR

    return closest

def closestRecursive(self, target):
    """ This is just a wrapper to call the actual function """

    return self._closestR(self._root,target) 






def main():

#BTSimple construct a tree from a list with the format
# [root, [Left Tree], [Right Tree]], where left and right tree has the same format

bt = BTSimple([6, [2, [-14], []], [8, [13, [11], []], [16, [15], [-18, [-9], []]]]]) 
bt.prettyPrint()

print("Closest to %d is node %d\n"%(11, bt.closestRecursive(11)))
print("Closest to %d is node %d\n"%(-14, bt.closestRecursive(-14)))

print("Closest to %d is node %d\n"%(-15, bt.closestRecursive(-15)))
print("Closest to %d is node %d\n"%(-3, bt.closestRecursive(-3)))
print("Closest to %d is node %d\n"%(20, bt.closestRecursive(20)))
print("Closest to %d is node %d\n"%(-22, bt.closestRecursive(-22)))

print("Closest to %d is node %d\n"%(12, bt.closestRecursive(12)))  





if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Since the tree is not ordered, you can't immediately return the left value if it's not `None`; you still have to check the right subtree to see if there's an even closer value there. What you need to do is compute the root's distance, recursively get the left and right subtrees' closest values, then pick which of the three is the closest overall.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at these lines:

```
    if distance == 0:
        return tree.key
    print("before traversing left, distance is " + str(distance) + " and closest is " + str(closest))
    valueL = self._closestR(tree.leftT,target,closest)
    if valueL is not None:
        print(valueL)
        return valueL
    else:
        print("None returned. Tree is : " + str(tree.key))
    valueR = self._closestR(tree.rightT,target,closest)
    if valueR is not None:
        print(valueR)
        return valueR
```

The only case you return None is when you reach a leaf.

This constructs a problem. Picture a tree with two branches. Your left branch will have a closest value, but your right branch will have the target. Because you don't compare the values and pick the closest to the target, you will return valueL, even though valueR might actually be closer.

Comment: Hi, thanks for taking the time to reply. This is a binary tree, not a binary search tree though, so the left and right subtrees are not ordered in the way you described. I do manage to get an exact match, but the problem is that when i return the value, in the base case where distance == 0, it get's lost as it returns only to the calling function, but does not "bubble" all the way to the top. Would you have any advice on how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution doesn't require threading any state around:

```
def closest1(self, target):
    candidates = [self.key]
    if self.leftT:
        candidates.append(self.leftT.closest1(target))
    if self.rightT:
        candidates.append(self.rightT.closest1(target))
    return min(candidates, key=lambda x: abs(x - target))
```

This has the drawback of recomputing the key of the locally closest value at each level of the recursion. You can fix that by returning both the value and its distance.

```
def _closest_helper(self, target):
    candidates = [(self.key, abs(self.key - target))]
    if self.leftT:
        candidates.append(self.leftT._closest_helper(target))
    if self.rightT:
        candidates.append(self.rightT._closest_helper(target))
    return min(candidates, key=lambda x: x[1])

def closest2(self, target):
    return self._closest_helper()[0]
```

Since the tree is unordered, the only optimization you can make is to return immediately on an *exact* match:

```
def _closest_helper(self, target):
    candidates = [(self.key, abs(self.key - target))]
    if candidates[0][1] == 0:
        return candidates[0]
    if self.leftT:
        candidates.append(self.leftT._closest_helper(target))
    if self.rightT:
        candidates.append(self.rightT._closest_helper(target))
    return min(candidates, key=lambda x: x[1])
```

Since the tree is unordered, conceptually all you are doing is gathering *all* the keys, and then determining which is the closest. You can do that with an all-purpose iterator

```
# left-to-right, pre-order traversal
def __iter__(self):
    yield self.key
    if self.leftT:
        yield from self.leftT
    if self.rightT:
        yield from self.rightT
```

Then applying `min` as for any iterable:

```
def closest(self, target):
    return min(self, key=lambda x: abs(x - target))
```